# Coding conventions for Linked Lists

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have been implementing [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nth-node-from-the-end-of-a-linked-list/) interview question in **Java** . A fairly simple problem with an additional ***constraint of size*** :

> ***Find the Nth Node from the end of a Linked List where the size of the Linked List is unknown?***

I am not concerned with the solution to this problem,because I have already figured that out.

*Instead, I want to know whether my implementation maintains the coding conventions which experienced coders maintain while coding a problem related to Linked Lists and it's implementation?*.Here is my implementation of the above problem:

```
import java.io.*;
class NthNodeFromEnd<AnyType>
{
    private Node<AnyType> head;
    private Node<AnyType> pointer;
    private class Node<AnyType>
    {
        protected AnyType item;
        protected Node<AnyType> next;
    }
    void push(AnyType item)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            head = new Node<AnyType>();
            head.item = item;
            head.next = null;
            pointer = head;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<AnyType> newNode = new Node<AnyType>();
            newNode.item = item;
            newNode.next = null;
            pointer.next = newNode;
            pointer = pointer.next;
        }
    }
    boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return head == null;
    }
    AnyType printNthLastNode(int n)
    {
        Node<AnyType> ptr1 = head;
        Node<AnyType> ptr2 = head;
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
        {
            ptr1 = ptr1.next;
        }
        while(ptr1!=null)
        {
            ptr1 = ptr1.next;
            ptr2 = ptr2.next;
        }
        return ptr2.item;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        NthNodeFromEnd<Integer> obj = new NthNodeFromEnd<Integer>();
        obj.push(1);
        obj.push(2);
        obj.push(3);
        obj.push(4);
        obj.push(5);
        obj.push(6);
        obj.push(7);
        System.out.println("The nth item is = "+obj.printNthLastNode(5));
    }
}
```

P.S. - I am aware of the fact that there is an **inbuilt implementation of Linked List in Java**, but I **don't want** to use that.I want to know whether this implementation of the problem is good enough or is there a better way to tackle Linked List related problems?

Comment: I wonder how they'd react if you answered something along the lines of "I'd modify the LinkedList source code to provide a method to find the size of the List, and then use that etc..."? That or just say you'd use a better LinkedList implementation, even if you have to write it yourself first! Arbitrarily complicating a simple problem serves no real purpose in an interview - though that's just my opinion.

Comment: @JonK Absolutely, but by better implementation I tried to mean something like "whether to go with a nested inner class implementation of a Linked List or with a normal inner class?". Something like this. I am asking this question because from my earlier interview experiences,I know that interviewers take a great deal of interest in the style or the manner in which a candidate codes.

Comment: Maybe this question would be more appropriate in the Code Review section of StackExchange. But to add something valuable to this comment: I think you should use conventional names, like add instead of push, and so on. It is really important for a teamworker to know the naming conventions.

Comment: @AttilaHerbert Yes, I got your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the code conventions:

- generic types are typically defined as a single uppercase letter: E or T, but not AnyType, which looks like a concrete type.
- operators should be surrounded by spaces, semi-colons followed by a space, etc. For example, `for(int i =0;i<n;i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`
- A method `printNthLastNode()` should print the nth last node, not return it. A method returning it should be named `getNthLastNode()` or `findNthLastNode()`. BTW, this method doesn't return a *node*, but a *value* stored in the list.
- methods should generally not be package-private. They should be public or private generally.
- the usual convention in Java is to have opening curly braces at the end of the line, and not at the beginning of the next line.
- your method `printNthLastNode()` will fail with a NPE if the list is empty or not large enough. A better exception type should be used to signal this problem.
- the class should not import `java.io.*`, since it doesn't use any class from java.io. packages should generally not be imported. Classes should.
- `String[] args` is more readable than `String args[]`, and is more conventional.
- the Node class should be static: it doesn't use any instance member of its enclosing type.

That said, the interviewer should see, with the code posted, that you understand how a linked list works and how pointers work, as well as generic types.

Comment: Thanks, this was the kind of input I was waiting for.Regarding your last point of the Node class being static, can you please elaborate a bit more about this.Apart from this, do you think a nested inner class is a good way to implement a linked list since I have seen many code snippets which do not follow this convention?

Comment: Yes. Node is a dumb class that doesn't need to be exposed anywhere else, so an nested class is a good choice. BTW, the standard java.util.LinkedList class does the exact same thing. A non-static inner class has access to all instance fields and metghods of its enclosing type. To do that, it has an additional field, cadded by the compiler, which references the linked list of which the node is part of. You don't need this reference, and it thus consumes memory for nothing. So the class should be static.